# does the depth of the prototype chain for an object affect the performance?

Tags: javascript, prototype-programming, prototype-chain

Several days ago,I post a question here about [class inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7349607/can-jquery-implement-the-class-inherit-like-prototype)

Then someone provide a link-- [a clever script](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/) for class inheritance by John Resig.

Then I try to use this script.

But I found that object created by this script will have a very deep prototype chain.

I use the example in the blog:

```
var Person = Class.extend({
  init: function(isDancing){
    this.dancing = isDancing;
  },
  dance: function(){
    return this.dancing;
  }
});

var Ninja = Person.extend({
  init: function(){
    this._super( false );
  },
  dance: function(){
    // Call the inherited version of dance()
    return this._super();
  },
  swingSword: function(){
    return true;
  }
});

var n=new Ninja(true);
console.dir(n);
```

With firebug I found this:
[image]

So I wonder does the depth of the prototype chain for an object affect the performance?

It seem there is a Endless loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The prototype of a constructor is the same constructor. So yes, you are looking at an endless loop.

However browsers don't follow the constructor chain when resolving object's members, it has an internal pointer (sometimes called `__PROTO__` but don't count on it) which is actually used. A JavaScript engine might also opt to compile to machine code which resolves the possible members in advance so no chain at all exists during actual execution.

I strongly doubt that you will experience any slow-down at all.

Answer (score 0):

It does affect the performance because it needs to follow the prototype chain to get the property's value.

Will this likely become the bottleneck of your application? I highly doubt it.

Comment: @hguser For some reason I feel compelled to clarify that Russell's question of the potential bottleneck was purely rhetorical.

Comment: Maybe I understand this poorly but how can an endless chain be followed to get the value?